# Generic autocompletion on properties

Tags: php, generics, phpstorm

I'm trying to implement basic Collection wrapper for array with use of generics to help me with autocomplete.

Collection code implementation:

```
/**
* @template T
*/
class Collection {

    /** @var array<int, T> */
    public array $items;

    /**
     * @param array|null $array
     * @var class-string<T> $className
     */
    public function __construct(?array $array = null, ?string $className = null) {
        $this->items = $array
    }

    /** @return T */
    public function get(int $key): mixed {
        return $this->items[$key];
    }

}
```

Definition:

```
/** @return Collection<UserVM> */
function sessions(): Collection { return $this->sessions; }

/** @var Collection<UserVM> */
private Collection $sessions;
```

Case 1: `$this->$sessions->get(0)-> (Doesn't have autocompletion)`

Case 2: `$this->$sessions()->get(0)-> (Has autocompletion)`

Is there any way configure the generics definition for properties in order to have the autocompletion working for Case 1? Maybe through php storm meta. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could it be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-63845 ? If not -- have a look at other existing tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%23%7BPHP%20Type%20Inference:%20Generics%7D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've looked to the issues that you mentioned, but can't understand the solution, or if this feature is missing.

Comment: "State: Open" -- that should give you a hint that the ticket is not yet implemented/resolved (if that's the correct one of course)